# Fast creation of data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

Is there a way to create a data.frame faster or smarter than the one I made below?

```
df <- data.frame(ID = rep(c("WT", "KO"), each = 4),
                 Time = rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), times = 2),
                 replicate(5,sample(0:100,8,rep=TRUE)))

colnames(df)<-c("ID", "Time", c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"))
```

The data.frame should still look like this

```
df
ID Time  a  b  c  d  e
WT    A 28 56 50 60 15
WT    B 54 77 11 67 34
WT    C 53  8 87 62 55
WT    D 30 73 47 82  1
KO    A 24 83 14 17 36
KO    B 91 83 72 41  4
KO    C 79 17 76 21 54
KO    D 41 40 77 49 92
```

Thanks

Comment: You can do somthing like `data.frame(expand.grid(c("WT", "KO"), LETTERS[1:4]), matrix(sample(40), ncol = 5))`

Comment: Thanks. How can include colnames together?

Comment: Can I use names instead of setNames? It does not work to me

Comment: I think just doing `names(df) <- c("ID", "Time", letters[1:5])` isn't so bad.

Comment: Were you going to accept an answer on your last question or did my answer not solve your problem?  I left several comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just use `expand.grid` for the non numeric unique combinations (sometimes you can even make use of built it data sets such `LETTERS`) and run `sample` only once while wrapping it up into a matrix, something like

```
set.seed(123)
data.frame(expand.grid(c("WT", "KO"), LETTERS[1:4]), 
           matrix(sample(40), ncol = 5))
#   Var1 Var2 X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
# 1   WT    A 12 36  6 11 24
# 2   KO    A 31 15  1 27 13
# 3   WT    B 16 29  8 22 25
# 4   KO    B 33 14 21 28 26
# 5   WT    C 34 19 32  4 20
# 6   KO    C  2 38 37 35  7
# 7   WT    D 18  3 40 10  5
# 8   KO    D 30 23 17  9 39
```

---

For less specific cases, I would recommend looking into @TylerRinkers [wakefield](https://github.com/trinker/wakefield) package which allows you to generate random data sets easily.

---

Just for general information, using `data.table` v 1.9.5+ you can now set new column names *by reference* using `setnames`. For, example if your new data set is called `res`, one could simply do

```
library(data.table) # v1.9.5+
setnames(res, c("ID", "Time", letters[1:5]))
```

Comment: In order to enlarge the numbers to be sampled I tried sample (0:100,8,rep=TRUE) instead of sample(40), but it did not work.

Comment: You mean something like `matrix(sample(100), ncol = 10)`? 100 doesn't divide by 8 equally.

Comment: I want to take my 40 numbers `matrix(sample(40)`  randomly from a bigger cohort, 1000 numbers, or even just randomly e.g. positive and negatives

Comment: You mean something like `matrix(sample(1000, 40), 5)`? I don't really understand you.

Comment: Is there any special reason to use `expand.grid` ? I tried to insert a new column just by `data.frame` here is my code: `df<-setNames(data.frame(ID=c("WT", "KO"), nrep_=c(1:8), Time=LETTERS[1:4], matrix(sample(1000, 40), ncol = 5)),c("ID", "Rep", "Time", c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")))`

Comment: `expand.grid` is to get all combinations of non-numeric values. If you have 3-4 different variables it will save you fighting out all the counts, and writing stuff like `rep`. In your case its not very needed because 4 divides by 2, but how will you do it for `ID=c("WT", "KO", "CA)` and `Time=LETTERS[1:7]`, for example?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87098/discussion-between-al14-and-david-arenburg).

Comment: What is seem to be the problem?